# Is there any tri-ply cookware where all the steel is 18/0?

Tags: cookware, stainless-steel

I like the characteristics of try-ply cookware but don't like cooking in 18/10 stainless steel because of the nickel (nickel allergy and concerns about persistent health effects). I notice that many try-ply brands out there use 18/0 on the outside to be induction-compatible (because it's the ferritic 18/0 stainless steel is magnetic), but they use non-magmatic austenitic 18/10 stainless steel on the inside. Are there any tri-ply cookwares out there that use 18/0 everywhere?

Comment: Are you concerned about nickel or do you have a genuine allergy to it? 18/10 is considered much better than 18/0 because it is less susceptible to galvanic corrosion. This mean that less of the material of a 18/10 pot will be transferred into food than the 18/0 pot.